# Why is my vertx promise getting set in handler when setting a vertx timer

Tags: groovy, promise, vert.x

I am getting an unexpected behaviour in my vertx v4.0.3 code.  I have created a simple script to show this behaviour.  In this example a create a wrapper method that takes a vertx.  In that wrapper i create a new Promise and assert it is not complete.

Then I call setTimer with a delay and a handler callback.

the weird bit happens within the timer handler.  I assert that promise.future is not complete, which it shouldnt be.  however the assert fails

weirdly if i remove the assert - then the promise.future().result() is a closure type.  If invoke that closure it just returns null).

between creating the new promise in the wrapper and the timerHandler firing 50ms later, what is completing my promise.  When I compare this to a similar example in "vertx in action" on page 101 this should work just fine

Can anyone explain why this is not working ?

groovy script tryout code sample

```
package scripts

import io.vertx.core.AsyncResult
import io.vertx.core.Promise
import io.vertx.core.Vertx
import io.vertx.core.Future

Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx()


Promise scrPromise = Promise.promise()
assert scrPromise.future().isComplete() == false

Timer timer = new Timer() // Instantiate Timer Object

// Start running the task on Monday at 15:40:00, period is set to 8 hours
// if you want to run the task immediately, set the 2nd parameter to 0
Closure task = {
    println "\ttask: in closure task on "
    assert scrPromise.future().isComplete() == false
    if (scrPromise.future().isComplete() == false) {
        println "\ttask: set the scrPromise to OK"
        scrPromise.complete("OK from task ")
    }
}
timer.schedule(task , 20, 10_000)

sleep (50)
println "script: slept 50ms "
assert scrPromise.future().isComplete() == true
scrPromise.future().onComplete(ar -> println "scrFuture is complete with :  ${ar.result()}")


void handler (Promise p) {
    def work = {
        return "delayed result, OK"
    }

    assert p.future().isComplete() == false

    println "\thandler is setting the promise with result"
    p.complete(work())
}

Future wrapper (vertx) {

    Promise promise = Promise.promise()
    assert promise.future().isComplete() == false  //this assert works 

    println "set timer for 50ms second "
    long tid = vertx.setTimer(50, {

        assert promise.future().isComplete() == false  //this assert fails 

        println "timer calling handler with promise "
        handler(promise)
    })

    promise.future()
}

Future future  = wrapper(vertx)
assert future.isComplete() == false


future.onSuccess({AsyncResult ar ->
    println "got result : ${ar.result()}"
})

sleep (1000)
vertx.close()
```

=== addenda ===

I tried again this morning and I saw an assert failure on the basic java timer I had added.  Which despite the assert failure seemded to show a result regardless in the println.

So I have just cut the example back down again, and removed the assertions altogether,
and crucially at the end I have changed from the future.onSuccess() to future.onComplete().

When I did that it seemed to start to work.  No idea what's going on, but the switch to future.onComplete () seems to then work correctly and I can of course check the AsyncResult for its status - so I guess I'll just stick with this model rather than the .onSuccess() and .onFailure() approach

```
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx()

Future handler (Promise p) {
    def work = {
        return "delayed result, OK"
    }

    def result = work()

    println "\thandler completes promise with the result of work() "
    p.complete(result)
}

Future wrapper (vertx) {

    Promise promise = Promise.promise()

     long tid = vertx.setTimer(20, {

        println "vertx timer calling handler with promise "
        handler(promise)
    })

    promise.future()
}

Future future  = wrapper(vertx)

future.onComplete({AsyncResult ar ->
    println "future.onComplete(): got result : ${ar.result()}"
})

sleep (300)
vertx.close()
```

Comment: I just extended the example with java deferred java timer task, and passed it a closure.  This seems to work fine and the asserts work ok for java scheduled timer.  still fails the assert in the vertx timer handler as before

Comment: could you show an example you are comparing to?

Comment: not readily - its on page 101 of the vertx in action manning book.  however see note below and yet another update of the main post

Comment: tried again, removed all assertions and crucially i switched from onSuccess() to onComplete() - see addenda example above.  This now appears to work.  Weird but there we are